# Display issues with details and summary and a re-aligned webkit marker (jsfiddle included), CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: css, webkit, alignment, hide, show

I have bumped into something of a rather trivial (But serious) issue. I have successfully implemented a function that allows me to hide and expand content (Courtesy to the HTML5 Doctor) through a custom symbol, in this case a "+" and a "-".

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amiralen/f6u26/)** I have successfully implemented a version of this code in jsfiddle. Below is an excerpt of the CSS:

```
   summary:-webkit-details-marker {
 color: 000;
display: none;
 font-size: 125%;
 margin-right: 2px;
 animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */  
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

summary:after {
  background: transparent; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  content: "+"; 
  color: #000; 
  float: left; 
  font-size: 1.5em; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin: -5px 10px 0 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 20px;
}
details[open] summary:after {
  content: "-";
}

summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */


}

article > details > summary {
color: transparent; 
font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 16px;
 animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

details > paragraph {
    margin-left: 24px;

animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

details details {
    margin-left: 36px;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

details details summary {
    font-size: 16px;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to have a version where the expand/hide symbol is merely aligned to the right. I attempted this, however **[it fails to function as planned](http://jsfiddle.net/Amiralen/z7q9s/)**, with the text not only prematurely displaying but with the symbol seemingly disabled from any kind of action. Indeed, my gut feelings is that I have done something really stupid, though ironically the realignment is the only thing that seems to have worked.

Without further ado, here is an excerpt of the CSS from the jsfiddle:

```
rsummary:-webkit-rdetails-marker {
 color: 000;
display: none;
 font-size: 125%;
 margin-left: 2px;
 animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */  
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}



rsummary:after {
  background: transparent; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  content: "+"; 
  color: #000; 
  float: right; 
  font-size: 1.5em; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin: -5px 10px 0 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 20px;
}



rdetails[open] rsummary:after {
  content: "-";
float: right;
}



rsummary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */
}



rarticle > rdetails > rsummary {
color: transparent;
float: right;   
font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 16px;
 animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}



rdetails > rparagraph {
    margin-right: 24px;

animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

rdetails rdetails {
    margin-right: 36px;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

rdetails rdetails rsummary {
    font-size: 16px;
animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Because I want two versions, where one marker floats to the left (Which I already have and properly working, see the first jsfiddle) and one that floats to the right, it becomes pertinent that the right one must function as well.

Alternatively, if there is a way to hide/expand the text by clicking the banner itself, I would be grateful as it is the way I really want it to work instead of using a +/- symbol. Obviously this means removing the hyperlink attached to the image, but that won't be a problem.

This has been bugging me for a couple of days now so I appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using tags which don't exist in the specifications.  The tags **`<details>`** and **`<summary>`** are what provide the hide/expand behavior.  You cannot simply rename them.  Further, there is only limited support for the behavior attached to these elements.  Specifically, there is support in Chrome, Safari and Opera, but none in IE or Firefox (http://caniuse.com/#search=details).

I see that you are using quite a few non-standards based tags.  For example: `<paragraph>`  and `<rparagraph>` instead of the `<p>` tag.  Accordingly, your result will be less than predictable.

If you want the hide/expand behavior of the details and summary tags on the limited browser set where it is supported, you have no choice but to use the supported tags.  If you want to have greater support, you can implement a fallback using Javascript or jQuery, such as this one: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suspected that the renamed tags would lay at the root of the problem, but I couldn't make sure. 

I will rename the tags into their supported names as you have suggested, but will this not create a conflict with my working example since the tag names will be the same? I need both a left-floating hide/expand symbol and a right-floating one.

For now I would like to stick with purely CSS3 as my knowledge on Javascript is non-existent. Thanks for providing a fallback, I will be sure to use it once I get this to work as intended. //Regards, DPP

Comment: Use classes instead of renaming the elements.  For example <summary class="rsummary"> would allow you to style this summary element differently by targeting the class selector.  You do that with a period before the class name in your style sheet.  So you might have something like:  .rsummary:after { /*your styles here*/ }.

Comment: Yes! It worked! :))))))))))))))))

I will upvote your answer and update my main post with the solution to this problem. Thank you so much for your time and thanks for the answer! //DPP

P.S. Shucks! 15 reputation required ;/

Comment: It's not about the points anyway.  I'm happy I was able to help.  Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

### Crossbrowser use of details and summary

In previous days, I needed to do some implementations with *details* and *summary* tags; Suddenly I found a compatibility problem between browsers, so traced several posts on different sites and some were confused. So I bring this site my conclusions.

1. Based in Nicolas Gallagher's [git.io/normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), review the *details* and *summary* tags in your CSS:

```
details, summary { display: block; }
```

2. Configure the CSS for this tags [sample in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jam65st/9rj9vvt3/)
3. In HTML, you need remember that **ALL details CHILDRENS** need be inside of a HTML tag as **p**, **a**, **div** or *other*; *Text out **HTML tags** will be showed on non webkit browsers in closed state.*
4. In JQuery you need a small code to switch states [sample in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jam65st/9rj9vvt3/)

**Note:** this is a low weight implementation with fine response; let me know your oppinions.

**Test on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jam65st/9rj9vvt3/)** Include code comments